# Emacs in an xterm...pagedown and pageup

Tags: emacs

When I start

```
emacs -nw
```

inside of terminal window on ubuntu, page down results in [6~ being inserted, and page up puts in a [5~

Any easy fix?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu, which version of Emacs, and which shell are you using? Page Up and Page Down work fine for me in bash using Emacs 24 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I"m using Mint 12, default terminal. I do have EDITOR and VISUAL set to VIM. I'm experimenting with evil mode for emacs and using vim, and page up and down work for vim. I just figured out that it's something in my .emacs file, as starting with -nw -q does not give me the issue. I've been using/modifying that emacs file since 1994...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using C-v instead of page down and M-v instead of page up (thus following the Emacs way :-) ).

Which Ubuntu? I can't reproduce your problem on Mint 12 (based on Ubuntu).